# Biztalk get data from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, biztalk

I'm trying to get data from a view on a SQL server through biztalk. What do I need to do? Read some documentation  but I think I only got more confused. Can't seem to generate the Schema.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the BizTalk project
2. Select Add, Add Generated Items
3. Select Consume Adapter Service
4. Click Add
5. Select sqlBinding
6. Click Configure
7. Select URI Poperties
8. Fill out InitialCatalog (database name)
9. Fill out InstanceName (if applicable)
10. Fill in Server
11. Click OK
12. Click Connect
13. Under Select a catagory: Expand Views
14. Select the view
15. Select either Delete, Insert, Select or Update.
16. Click Add
17. Give it a Filename Prefix
18. Click OK

Comment: Yes this ^^^^^. And this page is a bit more verbose but it has pictures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788445.aspx

Comment: I dont seem to have the consume adapter service, I was trying to use add adapter metadata ( not sure if it isn't possible in this one ) but i'm going to try to find a way to get the consume adapter :) will update as soon possible. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much ended up losing a bit more time because of machine.config not finding valid adaptors but for now it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem?  Views appear on the list of Client operations along with Stored Procedures, Tables, etc.

There's really nothing special about it.